# Create an or-proof for a given list of elements with public input

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, protocol-design, provable-security, commitments

Let $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ be two group generators. Given a list L of m group elements, where $L=(L_1,...,L_m)$, a prover wants to convince a public verifier (namely, a verifier who only has public input) that  one element $L_i$ in the list $L$ (without revealing i) can be produced from a public element $ u =u_i$ (where i should not be revealed) and some secret $s_i$, e.g., prove that there is some $i$ such that for which $L_i = g^{u_i}h^{s_i}$ for public $u_i$ and secret $s_i$. Is it possible to create such proof with Pedersen commitment or with Groth-Sahai commitment?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $s_i$ and $u_i$ must be scalars (positive integers less than the group order $\ell$ of the generator) and not field elements.

In additive notation:

You have a set of Pedersen commitments of the form $L_i = s_iG+u_iH$ where $s_i$ is the random blinding factor and $u_i$ is the value being committed to.

To prove that a Pedersen commitment $L_i$ commits the value $u$, just provide a signature for $L_i - uH$ on the generator $G$. This proves the values (on generator $H$) exactly cancel each other out, because if they did not cancel each other out the signature would not be possible (because $G$ and $H$ are chosen such that $h$ is unknowable such that $H=hG$). The private key, known only to you, will be $s_i$.

To prove that one of a list of Pedersen commitments is a commitment to a certain $u$ value, just provide a ring signature instead. This will prove that in at least one of the cases, you've committed to that value. The list of public keys in the ring signature would be $\{L_i - uH\}$, and only where $u\overset{?}{=} u_i$ will there be a knowable corresponding private key $s_i$.

Comment: Real world example: that's exactly what Monero's RingCT construction does with input amounts

Comment: I think that I didn't explain myself properly. The prover outputs a proof $\pi$ and the public $u_i$ (not a commitment to $u_i$) so that any verifier that is given the list $L$, $u_i$, and $\pi$ would accept iff there exist a an element in the list (which, e.g., is a pedersen commitment) that was generated from $u_i$.

Comment: @Doron ah, I see. I've updated the answer, it's almost the same as before.

Comment: Thanks @knaccc! That's indeed seems to be working! By the way, is it possible to even add another constraint that there is another secret $v_i$ s.t. $v_i\in [1..n]$ (i.e., each commitment is of the form $L_i = g^{u_i} h^{s_i}f^{v_i}$ such that $v_i\in [1..n]$?

Comment: @Doron is a $v$ value also publicly declared as part of the proof, just like the $u$ value is?

Comment: @knaccc, no the v value should be kept as secret, only contrainted to be on the range [1..n]

Comment: @Doron what is the objective? $s$ only exists to blind the commitment (to prevent it from being brute-forced to discover the value committed to). How does it help to blind it twice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135473/discussion-between-doron-and-knaccc).